# onBackPressed while setting an ArrayAdapter from background thread

Tags: android, runnable, ui-thread

I am trying to updat my UI thread from within a runnable. It works fine until I interupt the method by pushing the backbutton. When that happens, it crashes from a NPE. I need a way to stop this thread from updating if the back button is pressed. Thanks!

```
                  view.post ( uiRun = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                /* UI update */

                                areasAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CL);
                                areasAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                                mContactLog.setAdapter(areasAdapter2);
                        }
                    });
```

05-10 18:26:00.610 13511-13511/com.example.bryan.customer84 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
                                                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
                                                                                     at com.example.bryan.customer84.PhoneSearch$9.run(PhoneSearch.java:606)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: Can you share the crash log?

Comment: so if you press the back button, the activity is destroyed and you're trying to update an adapter, and get an activity which may be null

Comment: Yeah, the thread is still running which updates the adapter after the fragment is destroyed

Comment: add a null check inside run() for getActivity() != null

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access an activity that was already garbage collected... add a null check inside run() for getActivity() != null

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did and it worked like a charm.